# Re-train a frozen *.pb model in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

> How do I import a frozen protobuf to enable it for re-training?

All the methods i've found online expect checkpoints. Is there a way to read a protobuf such that kernel and bias constants are converted to variables?

---

**Edit 1**:
This is similar to the following question: [How to retrain model in graph (.pb)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379506/how-to-retrain-model-in-graph-pb)

I looked at DeepSpeech, which was recommended in the answers to that question. They seem to have [removed support](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/commit/46d1cece4f98d726d88579500734a95686cfe16b#diff-79c8372f97f7f5a6d8660bd265f836d7) for `initialize_from_frozen_model`. I couldn't find the reason.

---

**Edit 2**: I tried creating a new GraphDef object where I replace the kernels and biases with Variables:

```python
probable_variables = [...] # kernels and biases of Conv2D and MatMul

new_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    for n in sess.graph_def.node:

        if n.name in probable_variables:
            # create variable op
            nn = new_graph_def.node.add()
            nn.name = n.name
            nn.op = 'VariableV2'
            nn.attr['dtype'].CopyFrom(attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=dtype))
            nn.attr['shape'].CopyFrom(attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(shape=shape))

        else:
            nn = new_model.node.add()
            nn.CopyFrom(n)
```

Not sure if I am on the right path. Don't know how to set `trainable=True` in a `NodeDef` object.

Comment: Not sure why this post got so much downvotes. It is a perfectly legit question that many beginners have when learning TensorFlow.

Comment: For the time being, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379506/how-to-retrain-model-in-graph-pb). Actually the solution is quite hacky and requires a bit of advanced TensorFlow. Will provide the code with explanation later if I can find time :D

Comment: Hi @FalconUA, thanks for upvoting!

Comment: I did check that. DeepSpeech has removed support for initialize from frozen model. See this: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/commit/46d1cece4f98d726d88579500734a95686cfe16b#diff-79c8372f97f7f5a6d8660bd265f836d7 I couldn't find any reason for that. That's why posted another question. (I will edit my OP to inform the above)

Comment: @FalconUA, when you get a chance, see Edit 2. I tried editing the graph.

Comment: Just a small modified for Tensorflow 2.x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67702185/retrain-frozen-graph-in-tensorflow-2-x/67707618#67707618

Answer (score 8):

*You were actually in the right direction with the snippet you provided :)*

---

#### Step 1: get the name of previously trainable variables

The most tricky part is to get the *names* of previously trainable variables. Hopefully the model was created with some high-level frameworks, like [`keras`](https://keras.io/) or [`tf.slim`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim) - they wraps their  variables nicely in something like `conv2d_1/kernel`, `dense_1/bias`, `batch_normalization/gamma`, etc.

If you're not sure, the most useful thing to do is to visualize the graph...

```py
# read graph definition
with tf.gfile.GFile('frozen.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# now build the graph in the memory and visualize it
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('out', graph)
    writer.close()
```

... with tensorboard:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir out/
```

and see for yourself what the graph looks like and what the naming is.

---

#### Step 2: replace constants with variables (the fun part :D)

All you need is the magical library called [`tf.contrib.graph_editor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor). Now let's say you've stored the names of *previously trainable* ops (that previously were variables but now they are `Const`) in `probable_variables` (as in your *Edit 2*).

*Note: remember the difference between `ops`, `tensors`, and `variables`. Ops are elements of the graph, tensor is a buffer that contains results of ops, and variables are [wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167134/whats-the-difference-between-tensor-and-variable-in-tensorflow/44167844) around tensors, with 3 ops: `assign` (to be called when you initialize the variable), `read` (called by other ops, e.g. `conv2d`), and [`ref tensor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783909/internals-of-variable-in-tensorflow) (which holds the values).*

*Note 2: `graph_editor` can **only** be run **outside a session** – you cannot make any graph modification online!*

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge

# load the graphdef into memory, just as in Step 1
graph = load_graph('frozen.pb')

# create a variable for each constant, beware the naming
const_var_name_pairs = []
for name in probable_variables:
    var_shape = graph.get_tensor_by_name('{}:0'.format(name)).get_shape()
    var_name = '{}_a'.format(name)
    var = tf.get_variable(name=var_name, shape=var_shape, dtype='float32')
    const_var_name_pairs.append((name, var_name))

# from now we're going to work with GraphDef
name_to_op = dict([(n.name, n) for n in graph.as_graph_def().node])

# magic: now we swap the outputs of const and created variable
for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs:
    const_op = name_to_op[const_name]
    var_reader_op = name_to_op[var_name + '/read']
    ge.swap_outputs(ge.sgv(const_op), ge.sgv(var_reader_op))

# Now we can safely create a session and copy the values
sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs:
    ts = graph.get_tensor_by_name('{}:0'.format(const_name))
    var = tf.get_variable(var_name)
    var.load(ts.eval(sess))

# All done! Now you can make sure everything is correct by visualizing
# and calculate outputs for some inputs.
```

***PS:*** this code was not tested; however, i've been using `graph_editor` and performing network surgery quite often lately, so I think it should mostly be correct :)

Comment: Thanks @FalconUA for the detailed post. Looks plausible, I am testing it now

Comment: Have the following questions:

Comment: 1) In _var_name = '{}_a'.format(name)_ what is the significance of "_a" ?

Comment: 2) Don't we need to remember the _var_ object? Maybe have a dictionary that maps _var_name_ to _var_?

Comment: 3) _var_reader_op_ fails since _name_to_op_ doesn't have _[var_name + '/read']_. How will _name_to_op_ have _var_ since its working with the current GraphDef (which has constants)?

Comment: I am also debugging the above, appreciate all the help!

Comment: @schil **1.** you need your variable and constant have different names, so `_a` is just to provide a name that not existed in the graph yet. You can use any suffix you want. **2.** well, you can if it is more convenient for you. here we just have [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) do the job for us. **3.** Oh, my bad, here you need to create Variables **inside** the `graph` (the idea is we add new ops to our graph and use `graph_editor` to re-route. Will edit the code later :D

Comment: was traveling so getting to this only today

Comment: I am trying your suggestions in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896284/cloning-a-network-with-tf-contrib-graph-editor/53034296#53034296 Still having trouble adding Variables to a graph

Answer (score 4):

I have verified @FalconUA's solution with tested code. Slight modifications were needed (notably, I use the `initializer` option in `get_variable` to properly initialize the Variables). Here it is!

Assuming your frozen model is stored in `frozen_graph.pb`:

```py
probable_variables = [...] # kernels and biases of Conv2D and MatMul
tf_graph = load_pb('frozen_graph.pb')

const_var_name_pairs = []
with tf_graph.as_default() as g:

    for name in probable_variables:
        tensor = g.get_tensor_by_name('{}:0'.format(name))
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tensor_as_numpy_array = sess.run(tensor)
        var_shape = tensor.get_shape()
        # Give each variable a name that doesn't already exist in the graph
        var_name = '{}_turned_var'.format(name)
        # Create TensorFlow variable initialized by values of original const.
        var = tf.get_variable(name=var_name, dtype='float32', shape=var_shape, \  
                      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(tensor_as_numpy_array))
        # We want to keep track of our variables names for later.
        const_var_name_pairs.append((name, var_name))

    # At this point, we added a bunch of tf.Variables to the graph, but they're
    # not connected to anything.

    # The magic: we use TF Graph Editor to swap the Constant nodes' outputs with
    # the outputs of our newly created Variables.

    for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs:
        const_op = g.get_operation_by_name(const_name)
        var_reader_op = g.get_operation_by_name(var_name + '/read')
        ge.swap_outputs(ge.sgv(const_op), ge.sgv(var_reader_op))
```

Note: if you save the converted model and view it in Tensorboard or Netron, you will see that Variables have taken the Constants' places. You will also see a bunch of dangling Constants, which you can optionally remove.

I have verified that the weight values are the same between the frozen and unfrozen versions.

Here is the `load_pb` function:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# Load protobuf as graph, given filepath
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @FalconUA and @Max wu.
I added a way to quickly get the variables' names.

```html
import tensorflow as tf


# Load protobuf as graph, given filepath
def load_pb(path_to_pb):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_pb, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        return graph


tf_graph = load_pb('mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_frozen_ccl.pb')
variables = [op.name for op in tf_graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
print(variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def protobuf_to_checkpoint_conversion(pb_model, ckpt_dir):
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_model, 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def,name='')
    image_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
    dummy = np.random.random((1, 512, 512, 3))
    with graph.as_default():
        config = tf.ConfigProto()
        with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
            constant_ops = [op for op in graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
            vars_dict = {}
            ass = []
            for constant_op in constant_ops:
                name = constant_op.name
                const = constant_op.outputs[0]
                shape = const.shape
                var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, dtype=const.dtype, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
                vars_dict[name] = var
            print('INFO:Initializing variables')
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            sess.run(init)
            print('INFO: Loading vars')
            for constant_op in tqdm(constant_ops):
                name = constant_op.name
                if 'FeatureExtractor' in name or 'BoxPredictor' in name:
                    const = constant_op.outputs[0]
                    shape = const.shape
                    var = vars_dict[name]
                    var.load(sess.run(const, feed_dict={image_tensor:dummy}), sess)
            saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars_dict)
            ckpt_path = os.path.join(ckpt_dir, 'model.ckpt')
            saver.save(sess, ckpt_path)
```

reference: https://github.com/yeephycho/tensorflow-face-detection/issues/42#issuecomment-455325984

Answer (score 0):

def protobuf_to_checkpoint_conversion(pb_model, ckpt_dir):

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_model, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def,name='')

image_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
dummy = np.random.random((1, 512, 512, 3))

with graph.as_default():
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config) as sess:
        constant_ops = [op for op in graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
        vars_dict = {}
        ass = []
        for constant_op in constant_ops:
            name = constant_op.name
            const = constant_op.outputs[0]
            shape = const.shape
            var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, dtype=const.dtype, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
            vars_dict[name] = var

        print('INFO:Initializing variables')
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        print('INFO: Loading vars')
        for constant_op in tqdm(constant_ops):
            name = constant_op.name
            if 'FeatureExtractor' in name or 'BoxPredictor' in name:
                const = constant_op.outputs[0]
                shape = const.shape
                var = vars_dict[name]
                var.load(sess.run(const, feed_dict={image_tensor:dummy}), sess)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=vars_dict)
        ckpt_path = os.path.join(ckpt_dir, 'model.ckpt')
        saver.save(sess, ckpt_path)
```

reference: https://github.com/yeephycho/tensorflow-face-detection/issues/42#issuecomment-455325984